# Laravel controller not existing

Tags: php, laravel, controller, frameworks

I wanna redirect to my controller instead of a view but it says: "Target class [app/Http/Controllers/MyFirstController] does not exist. "

here is the code (web.php file):

```
//just a view
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

//just a view
Route::get('/final', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//the controller is interested in
Route::get('/hello-controller', 'app/Http/Controllers/MyFirstController@index');
```

Controller code (app/Http/controllers/MyFirstController.php) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyFirstController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return "viva";
    }
}
```

additional information:
Laravel Framework version: 8.83.17
PHP version : PHP 7.4.29

Comment: change `'app/Http/Controllers/MyFirstController@index'` to `'App/Http/Controllers/MyFirstController@index'`

Comment: 1ts a typo `'app/Http/......` should be `'App/Http/.........`

Comment: Namespace should be with back slashes.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace is not correct: Capital A for App and use `\` instead of `/`

```
Route::get('/hello-controller', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyFirstController@index');
```

or even better :

```
Route::get('/hello-controller', [\App\Http\Controllers\MyFirstController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to clear cache your controller by using

```
php artisan route:cache
```

and also maybe u should use

```
//the controller is interested in
Route::get('/hello-controller', 'App/Http/Controllers/MyFirstController@index');
```

Comment: i mean your route

Comment: No. nothing worked

Comment: here if u use laravel 8

Route::get('/hello-controller', [MyFirstController::class, 'index']);

Full documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: @LenaSeptiana I appreciate but it didn't work